# Groupby by specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two column, age and income. There are some income values in same age. How do I get the average from specific age?

If I try to use

```
df.groupby('age')['income'].mean()
```

I will get a dataframe, How do I get a value for a specific age?

Comment: (1) Format the code properly. (2) Add an appropriate tag for the library you are using (pandas, polars, spark,...).

Comment: `df.groupby('age')['income'].mean().loc[age]` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Comment: Are you just trying to do it for one age or do you want to get all of them then go through them one-by-one? Please [edit] and add some example input and your desired output. for reference see [mre] and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: FWIW, you might find your answer in the user guide: [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the `groupby` method followed by taking the mean will give you a series with the average income for each age in your DataFrame. If you want to get the average income for a specific age, you need to pass the specific age you're interested in.

I assume that you want the average income for an age of 30. You would do:

```py
average_income_age_30 = df.groupby('age')['income'].mean().loc[30]
```

This will first perform the grouping and mean calculation, and then use the `loc` method to retrieve the value for age 30.

Or, you can assign the result of the `groupby` and `mean` to a variable and then use that:

```py
average_incomes_by_age = df.groupby('age')['income'].mean()
average_income_age_30 = average_incomes_by_age.loc[30]
```